# How to create 3D perspective views of an image using OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, perspective

I have an image on the wall. I'd like to create its 3D perspective views by myself. Suppose the points on the images, camera location, orientation of the camera are given, how can I do to obtain the 3d perspective matrix to play with the original image?

I understand I can use the orientation of the camera to calculate the 3d rotation matrix, but I've no idea how to calculate the subsequent projection matrix...

I've come across [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#cite_note-3) (see Section Perspective Projection), but I don't understand what's going on after projection.. And what is the difference between the camera position and the viewer's position?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use openGl and its open example to solve your problem.

in bellow link there are good samples to undestand 3d reconstruction:
http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html

wish helpful